# "Jwplayer not loading ts file just loading m3u8 file"

Tags: javascript, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, jwplayer7

I am working with live stream for that JWplaye loading m3u8 and ts file. But after playing video for some time it's just loading m3u8 file with statuscode 200. it's not loading ts file.

I checked jwplayer state it's showing 'playing'. I checked with onError and onBuffer event but it's not going in those condition.

I expect it should load ts file or show some error

My code:

```
jwplayer("playback").setup({
  playlist: [{
    'sources': [{
      'file': "myPlaylist.m3u8"
    }]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your (relevant) code please?

Comment: jwplayer("playback").setup( {playlist: [{ 'sources': [{ 'file': "myPlaylist.m3u8" }] }]});

Comment: @CodeF0x - I noticed same scenario when i select slow 3g from my chrome devtool, while my stream is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load a .ts URL directly in JW Player. You would need to load the .m3u8 manifest instead or MP4 URL over HTTP protocol.

**Reference:**

https://jwplayer-support-archive.netlify.com/questions/16327329--ts-file-not-loading